# Read file asynchronously

Tags: node.js

I am trying to read a file using `fs.readFile()` and then use the result in the code that follows. The read process has to be asynchronous. Here is what I have so far:

```
var file = async () => {
  await fs.readFile(__dirname + "/file.json", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err
    return JSON.parse(data)
  })
}
console.log(file());
```

For some reason this code always logs `undefined`. Is there any way to do this without moving the `console.log` statement inside the `readFile` callback?

Comment: In your code above the `file` variable is a function. Specifically it is the function `async () ...`. Your code is similar to writing `async function file () { ... }`. That is, `file` is the NAME OF THE FUNCTION

Comment: So where should the `async` go? Because even `console.log(file())` does not work.

Comment: The `async` keyword just makes the function return a Promise. So your `file` function will return a Promise.

Comment: Ooh, ok. So how do I get the file data asynchronously?

Comment: You should wait for the result before logged it, const result = await file(); console.log(result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

notable modifications :
fs.promises.readFile => if you dont use promises dont use await.
it you do use promises => dont use callback.

```
async function readFile() {
  const data = await fs.promises.readFile(__dirname + "/file.json", "utf-8");
  return JSON.parse(data)
}

(async() => {
  console.log(await readFile());
})();
```

for a synchronous version see others comments. (but i prefer async for performance reasons)

Answer (score 1):

Use Promise

```
const someFunction = async () => {
    try {
        var file = () => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fs.readFile(__dirname + "/file.json", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
                    if (err) reject(err)
                    else resolve(data)
                })
            })
            
        }
        console.log(await file()); // this is the key
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

You need to add a `try-catch` block to catch the `reject` promise or any error that thrown. So it is better.

Or the older function style

```
async function someFunction() {
    // the contents are the same
    // ...
}
```

The problem is, the `file()` runs asynchronously and the code is not waiting for the result. Put `await` on the `fs.readFile()` function doesn't mean await the `file()` variable to finish its execution.